# How to setup SQL Server Express on local network with wireless router

Tags: networking, sql-server-2012, vpn, portforwarding

Guidance on how to connect to SQL Server 2012 needed.

- I am on Windows 10 Home Edition

  I have set up SQL Server Express to allow remote connections on my database machine to serve up data to three client machines.
- Firewall has been set for ports - **check**
- Allowed mixed mode logins - **check**
- Setup IPs through SQL Configuration Manager - **check**

The server is something like 192.168.1.40,1433 and I can login successfully through SQL Server Express on my client machines. I had a long LAN cable running along the floor which is not optimal. So, I went to the store and bought a router so that I could connect wirelessly but have limited experience in networking.

After, installation of the router I can no longer connect to SQL Server. This makes sense since there is another piece of hardware in the chain.

After doing an IP config on the command line I see that the IPV4 address has changed. I assume I am not picking up the private IP address of the router rather than the modem that I was initially connected to.

Should I be port forwarding?

What are my options?

I explored what I thought may be reasonable leads to get this working.

First, I tried to create a virtual server (I also assume this is how to port forward on my particular router). I didn't really know what to put in five fields that were given other than server name and Protocol TCP or if I was on the right track at all.

The other three fields consist of:

- **External Port**, **Internal IP**, and **Internal Port**

If this is a reasonable solution can you let me know what to put in these fields and any changes to the SQL Server configuration or firewall might be?

Should I VPN ?

After exploring this option on google I also notice people saying, "set up a VPN is the correct way to go." However, I don't really know how to do this. The only VPNs I know of are external VPN providers. It seems that I would be setting up a VPN server if I am not corrected(maybe on the server computer) and connecting via my client machines.

Any clarification or direction would be greatly appreciated. I am sure I have missed the mark on many things here but still would like to make ground.

Comment: You need to setup sql server on the all ip (0.0.0.0) with a static port so it is reachable over the WLAN IP as well. If you the need a port forward or not depends if your client is on the same logical network or not.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what state I should be in? Are you saying that I can forget about port forwarding any other setup since it was working with LAN and then make your recommended changes? Also, I am not sure what you mean by "setup server on the all ip(0.0.0.0) with a static port". Could you formulate a quick Answer?

Comment: If your client is on the same machine or the same lan you dont need port forward. You might need to enable "computers can talk to each other" in the WLAN router. You only need it if your wired LAN (or the Internet) has a different network segment.

Comment: BTW: the named SQLEXPRESS Instance does normally not use Port TCP/1433 but an arbritrary selected one. I dont have the configuration manager handy but it normally shows multiple interfaces "labeled ip" and one is the Any interface.

Comment: IPAll is set to 1433 in my configuration manager for TCP/IP. I am trying to connect through a wireless router.

Comment: In my router settings I also noticed something called SPI firewall. I am not sure how or if that factors into configuration. Still pretty much stuck and have no idea where to look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120672/discussion-between-jwize-and-eckes).